# Complex validation of an enitre backbone model

Tags: validation, backbone.js

I use the backbone's plugin [backbone.validation](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation) for model fields validations. I like the great declarative way of validation, which the plugin introduces. What I'm missing, is the way of validating not particular field, but the whole model. Here is what I'd like to have:

```
var SomeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  validation: {
    field1: {
      required: true
    },
    field2: {
      required: true
    },
    field3: {
      required: true
    }
    'whole model': function () {
      // this method makes some complex validation logic and expected to be 
      // called each time the validation of model (some fields) is performed
    }
  }
});
```

I can easy do this when not using backbone.validation plugin, but how can do the same when I'm using it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, see here: https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation#validate

`"You can also call it manually without any parameters to validate the entire model."`

The plugin overwrites Backbone.Model.prototype.validate behind the scenes. If you declared all your rules and call `modelInstance.validate()` it should validate ALL properties.

Comment: Do you suggest to declare some fake property and manually call `validate` method? It is what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Maybe I don't really see your point. No need for fake properties. You want to validate the "whole model", which sounds to me that you want to validate ALL properties at once, don't you? Here is a jsbin to demonstrate what I meant: http://jsbin.com/rimabenuje/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: The difference that I want to make some complex validation, which validates some conditions based on values of several (all) properties. For example `if (field1.length > 3) return field2.length + field3.length > 5`

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, then it looks like you'll need to implement this yourself. It seems that there is no way to trigger a custom function after validation is done, but I think you can easily do this yourself. Extend the validate function and put your custom logic in there if default validation was successful: https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation/issues/234

Comment: I was trying to implement a suggestion by the link, but it does not work well for me. I've made a tiny sample http://jsfiddle.net/_ie_/0u1qxwo5/10/ that shows the problem

Comment: This is the problem: "When binding to a view with a model, Backbone's validate method on the model is overridden to perform the validation. ...." - see this fiddle for working example: http://jsfiddle.net/v60tkad9/1/ - You'll need to extend the validate after binding to a view... (see the dev tools console)

Comment: Well, that is better. It is a big hack, but at least it gives a way. Anyway, with this hack invalid event is not triggered anymore. Do you have ideas why could it be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63779/discussion-between-mwager-and-ie).